# Spark SQL PIVOT - does not allow specifying columns in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot-table, databricks

I'm using Spark SQL on Databricks but this may apply to other SQL dialects as well.

I wonder why PIVOT only works when I select all columns

```
SELECT *
FROM events
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR event_name IN ('cart', 'pillows', 'login', 'main', 'careers', 'guest', 'faq', 'down', 'warranty')
)
```

BUT stops working when I specify certain columns

```
SELECT user_id, event_name
FROM events
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR event_name IN ('cart', 'pillows', 'login', 'main', 'careers', 'guest', 'faq', 'down', 'warranty')
)
```

The error message is quite verbose, here is the first line saying 'event_name' doesn't exist.
`Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Column 'event_name' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [finalize, foam, guest, original, premium ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that your query doesn't have `event_name` column in its output.

The `Pivot` clause will create a separate column for each value of `event_name` that you filtered using this expression:

```
FOR event_name IN ('cart', 'pillows', 'login', 'main', 'careers', 'guest', 'faq', 'down', 'warranty')
```

If you select one (or more) of those columns, it should work.

For example, try:

```
SELECT user_id, cart, pillows
FROM events
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR event_name IN ('cart', 'pillows', 'login', 'main', 'careers', 'guest', 'faq', 'down', 'warranty')
)
```

You can check here the official docs with a few examples:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot.html#examples

Comment: Ah I see, the table is first pivoted and then selected, I thought it was the other way around. Thanks a lot!